# iOS9 and HTTP with dynamic sources

Tags: http, https, ios9, app-transport-security

My app is remotely updated with image URLs from tons of different sources, most of these on HTTP servers. Now, these HTTP URLs won't download because of App Transport Security.

Apparently I have two options.

1. **Allow all HTTP URLs:** Bad practice, possible App Store rejection
2. **Allow specific domains:** Not possible because this would mean I can't remotely add images

How can I download the images without disabling App Transport Security?

Answer (score 0):

What if you programmed your own web based API that downloads and stores said images - then you can retrieve them with a call to it. Secure your API with HTTPS. This also gives you more fine grained control in that you own the server you are querying instead of accessing someone else's.

Comment: I have thought of this, but it would mean I also have to build and maintain a web server and I don't have time to do that for this app.

Comment: Check out Amazon Elastic Beanstalk - Might be useful for you. They maintain the web server and scaling. All you need to do is build the web app.